# Gnome 3 high CPU usage when moving windows, scrolling, or accessing menu ribbon

Tags: nvidia, gnome, ubuntu-gnome, cpu-load

I just installed Ubuntu Gnome 3 on my system and I found that when I move windows or access a menu from the ribbon or scroll my CPU usage shoots up to 80% if not more and my computer lags a bit. I am running my displays out of a NVIDIA GTX 1070 and when I run `glxinfo | less` I get the following:

```
name of display: :0
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, 
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_buffer_age, 
    GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile, GLX_EXT_create_context_es_profile, 
    GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_libglvnd, 
    GLX_EXT_stereo_tree, GLX_EXT_swap_control, GLX_EXT_swap_control_tear, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, 
    GLX_NV_copy_image, GLX_NV_delay_before_swap, GLX_NV_float_buffer, 
    GLX_NV_robustness_video_memory_purge, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync
client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    GLX_ARB_create_context_profile, GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness, 
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, 
    GLX_EXT_buffer_age, GLX_EXT_create_context_es2_profile,
```